# Partitioned Table Integrity in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, partitioning

One of the issues that I worked with in previous versions of SQL Server was working with maintaining data integrity on a partitioned table where the partition key was not part of the primary key of the records being stored on the table. Specifically, creating a unique constraint on the value that uniquely identified each record would generate a non-aligned index which would prevent using some of the more fun partition features such as swapping data.

Is there any way in SQL Server 2012 to be able to enforce unique values on a partitioned table to enforce data integrity and allow for foreign key relationships without disabling features?

Comment: I have the same question. The only way I know to achieve partitioning with aligned indexes and data integrity is to have the partitioning column as part of the index. For example, given T(int PK Id, datetime Timestamp),where Timestamp is the partition column, you can create a unique index {Timestamp, Id}. This has the side effect of ugly PKs.